# Python how to use ElementTree to find parent element of some element

Tags: python

I am using ElementTree of python to analysis xml, just like below:

```
<suite  id="s1" name="SW upgrade">
    <suite  id="s1-s1" name="BASIC FUNCTION">
         <test name="my test">
              <status status="fail"/>
         </test>
    </suite>
</suite>
```

I have found `test` element by below code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = [above xml content]
xmlroot = ET.fromstring(xml)
testElement = xmlroot.find(".//test")
```

my question: can i get parent element of testElement just like `testElement.parent()`?